# How to solve the summation part of the log likelihood of multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution

The probability density function of $X$ is
\begin{equation}
f(x)= (2\pi)^{-\frac{m}{2}} |\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp (-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu))
\label{pdf}
\end{equation}
where $X$ is a vector of $n$ observations, $\mu$ is a vector of $n$ means, and $\Sigma$ is $n\times n$ covariance matrix.

The log likelihood function is
\begin{equation}
\log \mathcal{L}(\mu, \Sigma) 
\propto -\frac{n}{2} \log |\Sigma|-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left((x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)\right) 
\end{equation}

I want to solve the part $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left((x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)\right) $
Which of the following is correct ?

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left((x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)\right)=
$$

\begin{pmatrix} x_1-\mu_1, \dots, x_n-\mu_n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
\sigma_{11} & \cdots& \sigma_{1n}\\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\sigma_{n1} & \cdots& \sigma_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1-\mu_1\\
\vdots \\
x_n-\mu_n\\
\end{pmatrix}

**Or should I do it like this**

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left((x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)\right)=
$$

\begin{pmatrix} x_1-\mu_1, \dots, x_1-\mu_n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
\sigma_{11} & \cdots& \sigma_{1n}\\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\sigma_{n1} & \cdots& \sigma_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1-\mu_1\\
\vdots \\
x_1-\mu_n\\
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{equation}
+ ................. +
\end{equation}

\begin{pmatrix} x_n-\mu_1, \dots, x_n-\mu_n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
\sigma_{11} & \cdots& \sigma_{1n}\\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\sigma_{n1} & \cdots& \sigma_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_n-\mu_1\\
\vdots \\
x_n-\mu_n\\
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: There's nothing to "solve" here, so presumably you mean *calculate.*  And for that purpose it's usually helpful to consider the simplest possible version of the question. So, when $n=1,$ what do you obtain? You might want to go further and ask yourself whether you even *need* to perform this calculation.  Ordinarily, the next step in working with a log likelihood is to differentiate it (if possible). That is easily done without calculating the sum and the result is much easier to work with afterwards.

Comment: I need to differentiate it with respect to a parameter including in $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, so I need to do the calculation first. For example, $\mu=rh$ and $Var=rh(1-h)$ and $cov=h(1-h)$ and I need to differentiate it with respect to $h$

Comment: The Chain Rule will require you eventually to take the $\mu$ derivative, so do this first: it reduces the quadratic terms to *linear* ones, making the calculations much simpler.

Comment: You are right.I have quadratic terms, and then it became very complicated when I tried to differentiate it and solve it for $h$, especially that both $\Sigma$ and $\mu$ are functions of $h$.Using the Chin Rule,I will first differentiate $(x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)$ with respect to $\mu$.To do this, can I use the the following rule while $\mu=rh$,the diagonal of $\Sigma$ is $rh(1-h)$ and off-diagonal is $h(1-h)$?
$$\frac{\partial w^TAw}{\partial w}=2Aw \text {if} w \text{does not depend on} A \text {and} A \text{is symmetric}$$
If not,any idea about how to do the derivative in this case?